# Erro ao executar Servidor em node.js

Tags: node.js, servidor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com esse erro ao executar o codigo depois de compilado, no momente de compilar não da erro.
Aguem poderia me ajudar?

```js
 db.beginTransaction (function(err){
     let ssql = "insert into pedido(id_usuario, dt_pedido, vl_subtotal, vl_entrega, vl_total, status) ";
        ssql += "values(?, current_timestamp(), ?, ?, ?, 'A')";

        db.query(ssql, [request.body.id_usuario, request.body.vl_subtotal,
                        request.body.vl_entrega, request.body.vl_total], function(err, result){
            
            if (err) {
                db.rollback();
                response.status(500).json(err);
            } else {
                var id_pedido = result.insertId;

                if (id_pedido > 0) {
                    const itens = request.body.itens; 
                    var values = [];

                    // [ [ 55, 1, 2, 33.8, 67.6 ], [ 55, 11, 3, 6, 18 ] ]
                    for (var i=0; i < itens.length; i++){
                        values.push([id_pedido, itens[i].id_produto, itens[i].qtd, itens[i].vl_unitario, itens[i].vl_total]);
                    }

                    ssql = "insert into pedido_item(id_pedido, id_produto, qtd, vl_unitario, vl_total) ";
                    ssql += "values ?";

                    db.query(ssql, [values], function(err, result){
                        if (err){
                            db.rollback();
                            response.status(500).json(err);
                        } else {
                            db.commit();
                            response.status(201).json({id_pedido: id_pedido});
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });  
    });         
});
```

Comment: Boa noite, precisaria ver o resto do código, mas pelo que entendi o compilador está tentando ler um atributo de undefined, no caso o atributo "length" de itens é nessa variável que se enontra o problema

Comment: Pois é, adicionei o codigo,

Answer (score -1):

Aparentemente era problema de acesso ao banco rodei `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'senha';

flush privileges;`
Resolvi.

Obrigado a todos

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).